# Security risks - uploading a JavaScript file in Node CMS portfolio website

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, ejs

I am building a portfolio website with a blog attached where I will show the web apps I have built, on the page. There will be a form where you enter the blog title, snippet, markup box, and file upload. I haven't started looking at data sanitization yet but I know ill need to do that for the markup on the server-side. But the idea is to upload the JS file to the header, which will then be rendered out by EJS depending on the page id, seems risky.

I could manually upload the file and then just specify the script name in the form to do the same thing but then the site isn't dynamic.

Or require a password before allowing upload?

How are you supposed to make a site like this dynamic without security risks?

Comment: What is `EJS` out of curiosity? For the mark-up, maybe using the `Markdown` language syntax would be appropriate here. On the server side, you would still need to HTML encode the content you receive for this. When it is read back out from the server to be displayed on the website side, Javascript has a method to decode it for display and rendering.

Comment: Is this your personal portfolio website, or a website for anyone's portfolios? Are you the only user of that CMS? If yes and yes, there is no additional risk (assuming the upload is properly secured) compared to you putting the template in the server code.

Comment: @ajawad987 [tag:ejs]

Comment: @Bergi Yes a personal portfolio site, and I'm the sole user. So I just need to make my login very secure I guess? I would have thought you need additional security for this. (I know I'm not a bank.. but in practice)

Comment: @chucky Yes, you just need to make sure nobody else can upload files through that server endpoint. (Which depends on the login, sure, but also proper checking of the authorisation in that upload method)

Comment: @Bergi Sorry when you say authorization for the upload method, you mean something like JSON Web Token authentication?